# TYPO3 automatically deactivate debug mode

Tags: typo3

Is there a way to automatically disable the debug mode of TYPO3.

It often happens that this is forgotten and so it can happen that visitors to the site see the TYPO3 stack traces, my idea would be to check this periodically once a night and switch from debug to live. Are there already implementations for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe have a look at devIPmask. You could set this to your own IP adress, so only you will be able to see the stack traces. This way you don't need to set the debug switch back.

Comment: If you are using GIT you can write a hook. Other options are Jenkins or even bash or PHP script run via cron.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such implementation but you could use the `typo3conf/AdditionalConfiguration.php` file and override the setting depending on the application context